# Incorrect behaviour of xsl:for-each in Java

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm seeing inconsistent behaviour when applying my XSLT with a Java program compared do testing with XML Spy.  Specifically, when using Java, the `xsl:for-each` directive does not seem to iterate over the entire list.  This is not the case when testing with XML Spy.

**My XML document:**

```
<metadata xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <maps>
        <geographicCoverages>
            <coverage key="ON">Ontario</coverage>
            <coverage key="MB">Manitoba</coverage>
            <coverage key="SK">Saskatchewan</coverage>
            <coverage key="AB">Alberta</coverage>
            <coverage key="BC">British Columbia</coverage>
            <coverage key="YT">Yukon</coverage>
            <coverage key="NU">Nunavut</coverage>
        </geographicCoverages>
    </maps>
  <entry>
    <string>GEO_COVERAGE</string>
    <list>
      <string>BC</string>
      <string>ON</string>
    </list>
  </entry>
  ...
</metadata>
```

**My XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="geoCoverageKey" match="metadata/maps/geographicCoverages/coverage" use="@key" />

<xsl:template match="/metadata">

<xsl:for-each select="entry[string='GEO_COVERAGE']/list">
    <xsl:value-of select="key('geoCoverageKey', string)" separator=", " />
</xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I test the above XSLT with XMLSpy, I get my expected output:

```
Ontario, British Columbia
```

**My Java test program:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws TransformerException {
    String xsltPath = "test_migration.xslt";
    String xmlPath = "test-migration.xml";
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsltPath));

    StreamResult result = new StreamResult( new StringWriter() );

    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(xmlPath), result );
    System.out.println( result.getWriter().toString() );
}
```

However, when I run the above Java test program, the output I get back consists of one value only; Ontario.  I'm at a loss as to why I'm getting this difference.

Comment: What processor are you using? The one for Java may not be XSLT 2.0 so the separator option in your value-of may not be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default processor in the JDK is Xalan. Xalan is an XSLT 1.0 processor. When an XSLT 1.0 processor is given a stylesheet that specifies version="2.0", it is required (under the rules for XSLT 1.0 processors) to ignore attributes that are not defined in XSLT 1.0. The "separator" attribute falls into this category. In XSLT 1.0, xsl:value-of outputs the first node in a node-set and ignores the rest.

The answer is to install Saxon, which provides XSLT 2.0 processing in Java.

Comment: You were absolutely correct, within a day or so I had arrived at the same solution.  Although your detailed explanation filled in the blanks as to the why.  Thanks a bunch!